# Ember find model by Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

In my Ember app, I have a complex model that looks like below (kind of contains 2-dimensional array)

```
[
    [
        {
            id: 'Section1_123',
            label: 'abc'
        },
        {
            id: 'Section1_456',
            label: 'xyz'
        }
    ]
],
[
    [
        {
            id: 'Section2_123',
            label: 'abc'
        },
        {
            id: 'Section2_456',
            label: 'xyz'
        }
    ]
]
```

There are a lot of other attributes, but this is the overall structure.

Now my question is can I drill-down & find a specific object. It has unique ids (as shown in the example above)

So I need something like model.findBy(Id)
I then need to change/set some values for that object. Say I want to change the obj.label from 'abc' to 'abc_NEW'

Just to add, The main model is actually a simple JS array...but the inside objects (e.g. those with id: 'Section1_123', etc) are actually Ember objects

Comment: Do you use EmberData in your app?

Comment: I have it as a dependency, but not really using it

Answer (score 0):

Most common approach to work with data in Ember is EmberData. And because the main credo of Ember is "convention over configuration" then a common way in Ember is the best way, in my opinion.

There are many ways how to deal with your data format. I would recommend to create model for each item:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  label: DS.attr()
  // other properties
});
```

Then you can make a custom serializer according [this article](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/models/finding-records/). The goal is to convert your arrays to list of EmberData models.

After this you can use standard [EmberData functions to work with data](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/models/finding-records/) (including access by object id, of course).